# Use PHP to rewrite the address bar?

Tags: php

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way, but I'll lay out the process I'd like my website to perform and then see what solutions you guys can think of.

At the URL

```
example.net/ShellySite/Form/form.php
```

There is a form to be filled out, then a submit button is pressed, and the website goes to

```
example.net/ShellySite/Controller/PHP/submitform.php
```

It goes here because it submits the details in the form to a database, what I'd like to do is basically instantly reroute the browser to a different page after the code at the submitform.php page has finished running, something like

```
example.net/ShellySite/Home/home.php
```

But I can't seem to get it to work. I've tried stuff like `header(Location:"example.net/ShellySite/Home/home.php")`
 but it just appends all that onto the end of `example.net/ShellySite/Controller/PHP/submitform.php`, and that obviously isn't what I want.

Any help would be great!

Comment: How are you redirecting? Show us the code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use absolute URLs:

```
header('Location: http://example.net/ShellySite/Home/home.php');
```

Comment: Coulda sworn I had tried that already... anyways it works now! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting can be done with **`.htaccess`** what you are looking for in redirection.

Since, you are trying to use absolute URLs, You are missing protocol in your request. Like `http` and `https`. Add them

```
header('Location: http://example.net/ShellySite/Home/home.php');
exit; // Dont forget to add this
```

Or use relative URLs like

```
header('Location: /ShellySite/Home/home.php');
exit;
```